# Both connection types (acceptor and initiator) in one FIX engine instance

Tags: c#, quickfixn

I would like to know if is it possible to have in one QuickFIX engine both connection types - initiator and acceptor. I am solving problem that I need to communicate with Bloomberg as an initiator and also with another company as acceptor.

Thanks,
Jarda

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this seems to work for me.
I have a project creating an instance of `ThreadedSocketAcceptor` to accept incoming connections and at the same time creating `QuickFix.Transport.SocketInitiator` to connect to one exchange, both within the same process, and it seems to work fine.

All is done as described in QuickFix/n documentation, no special tricks for having them in one process at the same time.

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for your answer, it sounds promisable. Next week I should start with acceptor testing so I will let you know, if it works for as well